# How do i hide certain forms like signin forms when a person is logged in?

Tags: php, forms, session, hide

Currently i am using sessions to accomplish that and everything like displaying an error msg to restrict access to a page to everything and it is messy.Is there a better way to do it?As of right now i only know php a bit.

Comment: i'd start with laravel. u get it by default there

Comment: @Brainmaniac I know that laravel is a php framework but is it any good?Idk I am just currently writing php the old fashioned way on sublime text

Comment: maybe it is BETTER to learn vanilla PHP before learning laravel.. but boy, it is so much slower... I'd recommend laravel, take one month membership on laracasts and you will be so much further ahead with your project than you would otherwise.

Comment: @Brainmaniac How's jquery for that?